# How to create animation inside CGContext

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I have a circle and I want to make it pulsate.

```swift
func drawCircle(context: CGContext) {
    let circle = CGRect(x: circleX, y: circleY, width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter)
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.systemPink.cgColor)
    context.addEllipse(in: circle)
}
```

But I just don't understand how to do it inside CGContext

Comment: You probably need to look at CoreAnimation, Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611170/1619193

Comment: @ShawnFrank Yes, I found this issue. But the fact is that I need to do more at a lower level than in that question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it using CoreAnimation:

```
func drawCircle(context: CGContext) {
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.systemPink.cgColor)
    
    context.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x,
                                  y: bounds.origin.y,
                                  width: bounds.width,
                                  height: bounds.height))
    
    context.fillPath()
    
    // Using CoreAnimation
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity
    animation.duration = 2
    animation.toValue = 1.5
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
    animation.autoreverses = true
    
    layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

[image: CoreAnimation pulse animation circle Swift iOS]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is that in my class there is no access to `layer.add...`. My class is responsible for rendering.

Comment: And in it I have to use `CoreGraphics`

Comment: @errorka - what is your class, maybe you can put basic code of your class and where the pulse will be rendered, how it will be used etc ?

Comment: I decided to forward the layer to my class and do as you answered